# How to make web API Post method call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a solution with two project , one is my webapi service and another is my mvc for project . I am calling the service from my controller. My service has GET,POST,PUT all methods. In my view i am using a submit button and which calles the post controller method which in turn call my service . Here the issue i am facing is it is calling always the GET method. I want to fire the POST method in my service

controller post method

```
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(Test test)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    Test objTest  = MyService.Create(test);

                    if (objTest  == null)
                    {
                        return HttpNotFound();
                    }


                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            }
```

Here calls the service

```
    **public Test Create(Test test)
    {
        string uri = baseUri + "Test/";
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Test)));

           return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<Test>(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).Result;
         }
    }**
```

This is the post

```
    **// POST api/Test
    public HttpResponseMessage PostTest(test test
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Test.Add(test);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, test);
                    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = test.TestID }));
                    return response;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
            }


****************
**// GET api/Test
        public IEnumerable<Test> GetTest()
        {
            var tests= db.Tests;

            return tests.AsEnumerable();
        }**
```

It always calls the above Get method . I am completely new to web api service. Can some one guide me with proper way , where i am wrong. I am not using any ajax to call post method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how you do a POST with some data.It's similar to the GET request but in this case since you want to send a POST this will be aplicable. Also notice its  simple to add POST data (when compared with HttpWebRequest)

```
httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(data));
```

Comment: I think as david said i need to serialize it. My case test is an obeject and not a string. If i use strigncontent i will get invalid argument exception

Comment: httpClient.PostAsync(uri, Object);

Answer (score 3):

Well, look at the method you're using:

```
httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

`Get` does exactly what the name implies.  It makes a `GET` request to the resource.  If you want to use a different HTTP verb, use one of the [other methods available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient).

For example:

```
httpClient.PostAsync(uri, someContentObject);
```

Or, using [`HttpClientExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.aspx):

```
httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, test);
```

Comment: Thanks for showing up the mistake . Here can you tell me what is someContentObject . Is it the object (in my case test) ?

Comment: @jubi: It's an `HttpContent` object, which can be thought of as a kind of general container for whatever payload you want to send it.  For example, you might JSON-serialize your object and create a `StringContent` from it to use here.

Comment: Thank you. I should google to see how i can Json serialize my object . I will try and let know if it works

Comment: @jubi: The link in my answer is to the official documentation, which itself references other materials as well.

Comment: Can i ask you how i can Json serialize my object Test and creare string content

Comment: @jubi: Take a look at the Newtonsoft Json.Net library (available on NuGet).  It's pretty much become the standard for JSON serialization and de-serialization in the .NET space.

Comment: @jubi: Even better, use the `HttpClientExtensions` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions(v=vs.118).aspx  This has generic helpers which will handle the serialization for you.  So you can just pass your object directly to the method.

Comment: sure. JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test) - used to serialize myobject . Now i just neet to get string content as you said.

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft Json.Net library

Comment: @jubi: I definitely recommend using `HttpClientExtensions` to make it easier.  But with Newtonsoft serialization you should end up with a string, which you can then use in `new StringContent(yourString)`.

Comment: I just tried new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test)) . But this ddnt work .

Comment: I have modified the code as below. Task<HttpResponseMessage> response  = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test)));

Comment: I wonder whether you can update my method below to serialize and then deserialise the result.   I am using Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test)));   Is this right  Here i am saving Test object data to database .    I have copiedcontenetofmyquestonhere

Comment: publicTestCreate([FromBody]Testtest)
{stringuri=baseUri+"Test/";
using(HttpClienthttpClient=newHttpClient())
{Task<String>response=httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
returnJsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<Test>(response.Result).Result;
}}

Comment: public TestCreate([FromBody]Test)
{string uri = baseUri + "Application/";
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{public TestCreate([FromBody]Test)
{string uri = baseUri + "Test/";
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test)));
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<Test>(response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Test>()  }} I have seen some example of using response.Content.Read. AsAsync to desrialize , but i am not getting the Content method in httprespose object.

Comment: @jubi: Shouldn't the code be *awaiting* those "async" calls?

Comment: @jubi: Please stop dumping unreadable code into comments.  If you have more information to add to the question, add it to the question and explain the problem further.  If it's a new issue, create a new question.  Comment threads are not a substitute for a debugger.

Comment: I just deleted the comments. The problem is still the same, it is not identifying the POST method.I have modified and highlighted my changed code . Are you getting any clue on what mistake i made in code.Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: @jubi: Is it going to a different method?  No method?  What is the response from the server?  What is the updated code?  Also, calling `.Result` could be tricky, depending on the synchronization context.  Using `await` tends to be more reliable in web applications.

Comment: @jubi: Can you try defining specific routes in attributes on those methods?  Perhaps the routing isn't working for some reason not shown here.  If you make the routes decidedly different, that could shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not going to any of the method. ..Its just executing and none of the method is getting called (neither get nor post)My URI is http://localhost:9418/api/Test/Solution.Models.Test . Is this is right . OR http://localhost:9418/api/Test/ .is right

Comment: You mean HTTPPOST attribute in my post method?

Comment: @jubi: The URL depends on your routing.  Out of the box, a `TestController` would be something like `/api/Test` and the method on that controller would simply be called `Post`.  Are you checking the response from the server at all?  It could contain some significant clues regarding the problem.

Comment: Modified the method name to Post from PostTest And added [httpPost]on method call. But still no luck ..oof

Comment: response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result -  shows an error :  I think this may be the problem .....Value-typed properties marked as [Required] must also be marked with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] to be recognized as required. Consider attributing the declaring type with [DataContract] and the property with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)].

Comment: @jubi: Sounds like you've found some more underlying problems to debug further, then.  It's really outside the scope of this original question at this point.

Comment: Thanks David for showing me the mistake of marking GetAsync instead of PostAsync .. That really helped me to debug

Comment: David : I have just removed model validator and tested . Not it is hitting the service Post method. But the model object value is not binded. Its all null..Can you show some example . I have found from google to add [FromBody] attribute in service. But it is coming null still

Comment: @jubi: Maybe the serialization isn't matching what's expected?  See if you can capture the actual request content being sent (maybe using something like Fiddler?) to see if the JSON matches the expected model.  You might also try simplifying the serialization as previously suggested by using the `HttpClientExtensions` to let the framework serialize for you.

Comment: I have tried with HttpClientExtensions  to serialize and it worked .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103120/discussion-between-jubi-and-david).